# Remove inconsistency from status-declined

Tags: support, meta, tag-wiki, moderator-tags

If you look at the [status-declined page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-declined&sort=info&pagesize=15) you'll see that it starts off with "This is a moderator-only tag.." None of the other moderators tag say this, so can we remove this?

Comment: Or add it to the others?

Comment: @Bobby either add it to all or remove it from all I say, just odd to me with the inconsistency

Answer (score 10):

I'm for adding it to all (moderator) tags.

Answer (score 3):

It's a *wiki* - just get a bunch of votes on bad suggestions, and you can edit it yourself!

Comment: Too bad there's no revision history yet. I'm curious who is telling us to blame Jon Seigel.

Comment: @mmyers: Indeed, it's a mystery... I suspect Jon Seigel.

Comment: Self-framing... ftl :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-declined&sort=stats I'd love to make a hilarious edit, but as you can see, I don't have enough votes in that tag.